# Add a google gadget to webpage

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-gadget

I'd like to add a google calendar gadget to a webpage.

This page shows the gadget
http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/calendar3.xml

The linked page includes code to paste into a webpage
http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fig%2Fmodules%2Fcalendar3.xml&lang=en

I tried creating a simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>
<body>
*<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/calendar3.xml&amp;up_calendarFeeds=&amp;up_calendarColors=&amp;up_showDatepicker=1&amp;up_showEmptyDays=0&amp;up_showExpiredEvents=1&amp;synd=open&amp;w=320&amp;h=447&amp;title=Google_Calendar&amp;lang=en&amp;country=ALL&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>*
</body>
</html>
```

but the resulting page does not display a calendar, just '**'. I'm storing this page in a local file (not on a server) and opening in a browser.

Any suggestions, including another way to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The information on this page leads to a solution:

https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en